# How to map Alt+H to the Arrow-left key?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to have my HJKL keys to function as arrow keys whenever the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed down. Also other combinations should work, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> should be seen when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is pressed.

I've tried loading the following `alt_vim.kmap` file with `loadkeys`:

```
alt keycode 35 = Left
alt keycode 38 = Right
```

It does work when I open a new console, e.g. tty2 (ctrl-alt-f2). At least it will move the cursor when pressing h or l in combination with the alt key. However inside X (tty7) it does not respond to it (I have disabled the menu bar showing on <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in Unity already).

I used the GNOME terminal (3.6.2), but my question is not about a specific program, but rather to simulate those keys around the whole OS.

System: Ubuntu 14.10

Summary: Can I map my HJKL keys to the arrow keys under X?

Comment: Are you using Gvim or running Vim in a terminal? If the latter, in which terminal emulator?

Comment: I used the GNOME terminal (3.6.2), but my question is not about a specific program, but rather to simulate those keys around the whole OS.

Comment: Ok, then you need to configure this at the X level, with XKB. (The setting with `loadkeys` only applies to text mode consoles, not under X.)